# Error while building a docker image of a flask app

Tags: docker, flask, ubuntu-14.04, dockerfile

This is the flask app:

```
`From flask import Flask
 app = Flask(__name__)

 @app.route('/')
 def hello_world():
    return 'Flask Dockerized'

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')`
```

This is the docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 
MAINTAINER Ashish John Stanley "a*********@gmail.com"    
RUN apt-get update -y  RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential  
COPY . /app  WORKDIR /app  RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]    
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Command to build docker file:

```
docker build -t flask-container:latest. -f --file="~/Documents/web/requirements.txt"
```

The execution of the command gives the following error [terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrRi0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--file` should be pointed to a directory that contains `Dockerfile`

Here is a command to create docker image for your case:

```
docker build -t flask-container:latest .
```

Make sure you are running it from the directory that contains `Dockerfile`

Docker documentation:

> ```
> --file , -f       Name of the Dockerfile (Default is ‘PATH/Dockerfile’)
> ```
>
> By default the docker build command will look for a Dockerfile at the
>   root of the build context. The -f, --file, option lets you specify the
>   path  to an alternative file to use instead. This is useful in cases
>   where  the same set of files are used for multiple builds. The path
>   must be to a file within the build context. If a relative path is
>   specified then it is interpreted as relative to the root of the
>   context.

Here is more info about Docker options

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options.

Comment: ran the command to create docker image.
    `unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/ashish/Documents/web/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`
This is the error I get.

Comment: got the container running.